# Any Java class that enforces LIFO?

Tags: java, data-structures

The `Stack` class inherits methods from `Vector` including `get(int index);` and `add(int index, Object element);`. In other words: not very stack-like.

The `Deque` interface implements methods that behave like both a FIFO Queue and a LIFO Stack, hence the acronym "Double Ended Qeueue".

So, in reality, is there any Java class or interface which is designed to create a structure which enforces a LIFO rule?

Comment: @Eric Woodruff, The accepted answer to that question didn't have an anything to enforce LIFO. Using the LinkedList class doesn't answer this.

Comment: What is your problem? If you don't want to use methods which are not related to stack, just don't use them. Why do they disturb you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
Collections.asLifoQueue(deque);
```

More information in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#asLifoQueue%28java.util.Deque%29).

Comment: +1 I better do a Collection refresher course. I've never seen (noticed) this method before.